# Will the Linux Open VPNC Client connect to checkpoint or nortel VPN gateways?

Tags: linux, cisco, checkpoint, vpn

Site: http://www.oucs.ox.ac.uk/network/vpn/linux-solaris/index.xml?ID=VPNC

What is open VPNC:

VPNC is an open-source VPN client for Linux and other Unix systems which is compatible with the OUCS VPN Service and which offers some advantages over the ‘official’ Cisco VPN client for Linux

My question:

So VPNC will connect to Cisco VPN gateways. 
But will it connect to Checkpoint's or Nortel's gateways as well?

IF NOT:

then please advice if there are some other tools like OPEN VPNC that can service checkpoint or Nortel VPNs ?

Comment: Apparently there are patches to vpnc to support Nortel's gateways - see http://www.foscode.com/connect-nortel-contivity-vpn-ubuntu/

Comment: but the link above explain the cisco not nortel ? ( http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~massar/vpnc/ )

Comment: the second part - I work with linux red-hat is it support red-hat?

Comment: The article is describing how to compile a patched-up vpnc source - apart from the prerequisite installation, this is distribution-agnostic. The unix-ag.uni-kl.de link you are referring to is the home of the original vpnc project, managed by Maurice Massar. The unpatched vpnc version would only support the listed gateways. The patches from the `vpnc-nortel` development branch would bring the Nortel gateway support.

Comment: what about checkpoint VPN ?

Comment: It seems like you can connect to Checkpoint's VPN-1 gateways using most IPSEC clients, including OpenSWAN. There is an ancient interop document at http://www.vpnc.org/InteropProfiles/checkpoint-profile

Comment: seems this doc is for WIN OS and not linux ,

Comment: This is just an "interop" document for setting up an interop profile on a Checkpoint VPN-1 gateway which can be accessed by any client with the counterpart of the interop profile set up. It does not tell you, how to configure your Linux client to connect to it.

Comment: hi . this doc and this vpn from checkpoint required changes on the gateway , I cant use this vpn because I not allowed to change anything on gateway side